# What is the most railsy way to do this query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following 'find_by_sql' to find users who have a birth_date in the current day/month.

```
models/employee.rb
...    
def self.find_by_birth_date_this_day_and_month
    Person.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM people WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM birth_date) = #{Date.today.month} AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM birth_date) = #{Date.today.day}").map{|p| p.employee}
end
```

I want to transform this into an activerecord query, preferably not using raw sql like I'm doing right now. any suggestion?

Comment: I'd go with `Employee.where(person_id: Person.select(:id).where(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('to_char',[Person.arel_table[:birth_date],Arel.sql("'MMDD'")]).eq(Date.today.strftime('%m%d'))))`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a string match of the date, matching only the zero-padded, dash-separated, month and day parts:

```rb
Person.where("birthdate LIKE ?",Date.today.strftime("%%-%m-%d"))
```

`%%` is an escaped '%' symbol in strftime format, here in sql 'LIKE' matching, it means 'preceded by any string'